# Do I need to explicitely specify class using intent.setClass?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I want to use AlarmManager to schedule a repeating task. Basically, I have this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_TICK);
// The following line prevents the broadcast receiver from being notified:
intent.setClass(context, MyScheduler.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, intervalInMs, intervalInMs, pendingIntent);
```

I register `MyScheduler` as a broadcast receiver in its constructor:

```
context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(INTENT_ACTION_TICK));
```

Everything works as expected (receiver is triggered) unless I add the `intent.setClass`. Fine with me, however, I distinctly remember reading that you should use explicit intents (`intent.setClass`) for security reasons.

Is this something I have to consider for my use case?

Comment: @Christine It is working if I don't specify the class and just use the action. Only once I specify the class, the class no longer receives the broadcast. I updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: According to the docs, Context.registerReceiver "cannot be called from a BroadcastReceiver component; that is, from a BroadcastReceiver that is declared in an application's manifest."  Even though it's working without the setClass(...) call, does that apply to MyScheduler?

Comment: @EdmundJohnson No, it is not declared in the manifest, the intent filter is just programmatically added in the constructor of MyScheduler (which extends BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: Did you get this somehow working? I have this problem - intent without a class works, but the app is refused in the Play Store due to security issues. When I add a class, the code stops working (the alarm is not triggered).